# What does "LAWS" mean when appearing in a bank statement?

Tags: united-kingdom, online-banking, bank-statements

Some of the transactions on my bank statements have the code "LAWS" appearing in them, followed by a 6 digit code. It is also preceded by the payer's name.

Does "LAWS" mean anything in finance systems? Or is it a bank-specific thing?

This is on a UK bank statement

Comment: What country?  What does the bank say?

Comment: Is this "LAWS" showing up on transactions from different merchants/payers or always the same one?

Comment: It shows up on a variety of transactions. The 6 digit code is different per payer

Comment: Does "payer's name" and "different per payer" imply these are _only_ on payments to you? Looking at the group of payers that _do_ have "LAWS" against them, and the group that _doesn't_... is there that distinguishes the two groups (method of payment, type of transaction etc.)? Do you feel happy saying which bank you are with, as that might help searching for an answer.

Comment: Does "different per payer" imply that a particular payer will always have the same six-digit code? Could it be the payer's bank sort code? Could you include a couple of examples in your question? Also: why have you not asked your bank what it means? If they give details, you could post an answer here for other people in the same quandary.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but perhaps it is **Location-Aware Web System**. The phrase is used in [one paper I found](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3de3/6153ea8da16c672694824da9852bed9da603.pdf), though it is not specifically related to banking/finance.

As an example of how a credit card company might use this feature, see Visa's [website about Mobile Location Confirmation](https://developer.visa.com/capabilities/mlc).

However, I have no idea if this is common, and I can't find anything about LAWS showing up on bank statements.